# back link but not use history

Tags: javascript, php, base-url

how to make back a href but not use history back

i have try to write this
config.php

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/webapp/';
```

and at index.php
( i have no idea to replace :

```
 else{ die("wrong password <a href=\"javascript:history.back()\">back</a>");
```

the final goal is
on index.php is form login
than if it's ok then next page.
if wrong then i want to create link back to http://localhost/webapp
not http://localhost/webapp/index.php or other history url

Comment: Then set `href` to `http://localhost/webapp/`

Comment: how put it using include config.php variable ?... so when i use this script on other site i just edit config.php

Comment: Can you use `die("wrong password <a href=\"" . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] . "\">back</a>");` for this?

Comment: excellent .... that what i mean... searching at google i did not found the answer .... last question .... at google what keyword i should to use if i want to search help about this http_referer ?

Comment: Maybe you could use `substr( $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], 0, strrpos( $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], '/' ) )` to remove the filename

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you want:

```
die("wrong password <a href=\"" 
    . substr( $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], 0, strrpos( $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], '/' ) ) 
    . "\">back</a>");
```

**Edit:**
This will send you back to  http://localhost/webapp not http://localhost/webapp/index.php

Answer (score 1):

```
die("wrong password <a href=\"" . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] . ".'/webapp/'">back</a>");
```

Comment: This does not work since HTTP_REFERER will give you the hostname and filename... and create a URL like this: http://localhost/webapp/index.php.'/webapp/'

Answer (score 0):

There are some options to choose from, each has a *downside*

#### Base URL

You can use the base URL defined in `config.php`

```
die('wrong password <a href="'.$config['base_url'].'">back</a>'); // repalce `"` with `'` to remove `\`; this a preference
```

This seems like the best option, however, the browser with request `$config['base_url']` again. Unlike, `back` option which will go a step back (and leave all fields (inputs) as they were before submitting)

#### History API

```
 else{ die('wrong password <a href="javascript:history.go(-1)">back</a>');
```

This may and may not work, based on some condition, for example, having a set of previous pages in the history.